# Linearity of Variance

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

Is $Var(X + Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y)$ generally, for two random variables $X, Y$?
Is $Var(aX) = a^2Var(X)$ generally?

Important:
In which cases, $Var(X + Y) \leq Var(X) + Var(Y)?$

$Var$ = Variance

Comment: $Var(aX)=a^2Var(X)$ is clearly an indication of non-linearity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course it is not linear. But if you just want to know when $\text{Var}(X+Y)=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)$ holds, you can see the fllowing
$$\begin{align}\text{Var}(X+Y)&=\mathsf E(X+Y-\mathsf E(X+Y))^2\\
&=\mathsf E(X+Y-\mathsf EX-\mathsf EY)^2\\
&=\mathsf E((X-\mathsf EX)+(Y -\mathsf EY))^2\\ 
&=\mathsf E(((X-\mathsf EX)+(Y -\mathsf EY))((X-\mathsf EX)+(Y -\mathsf EY)))\\ 
&=\mathsf E((X-\mathsf EX)^2+ \mathsf (X-\mathsf EX)\mathsf (Y-\mathsf EY)+ \mathsf (Y-\mathsf EY)\mathsf (X-\mathsf EX)+ \mathsf (Y-\mathsf EY)^2)\\
&=\mathsf E(X-\mathsf EX)^2+ \mathsf E(Y-\mathsf EY)^2 +\mathsf 2E((X-\mathsf EX)\mathsf (Y-\mathsf EY))\\
&=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)+2\text{Cov}(X,Y)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $\text{Var}(X+Y)=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)$ only when $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=0$, that is when $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: Uhm, yes, you can. If $\mathsf {Var}(X+Y)=\mathsf {Var}(X)+\mathsf {Var}(Y)$, then $\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y)=0$ and the variables *are* uncorrelated (since that is what it means). $~$ (What you cannot conclude is: independence.)

Comment: @GrahamKemp Honestly, I was referring to the general case $\text{Var}(\sum X_i)$ in the last part.

Comment: Oh, yes, when you have *more than two* variables, then the sums of covariances being zero cannot be used to infer the individual covariances are.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\mathbb{V}(X) = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]$ (1)

By invoking the **linearity of $X \mapsto \mathbb{E}[X]$** (which results from **linearity of the integral**), one has $\mathbb{V}(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2$. Then $\mathbb{V}(aX) = a^2\mathbb{E}[X^2] - a^2\mathbb{E}[X]^2 = a^2\mathbb{V}(X)$. Now see for yourself if $\mathbb{V}(X + Y) = \mathbb{V}(X) + \mathbb{V}(Y)$ using (1) (*spoiler*: it is not).